# Finding the maximum value of $\displaystyle \frac{x^n-a\sin x}{x^{n+1}}\ (x\gt 0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

For $a\ge 1\in\mathbb R,n\ge 1\in\mathbb N$, let us define $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\frac{x^n-a\sin x}{x^{n+1}}\ \ \ (x\gt 0).$$
Also, let $M(a,n)$ be the maximum value of $f(x).$

We may be able to know the approximate value of $M(a,n)$ using some tools, but...

> **Question 1** : Can we represent $M(a,n)$ by $a,n$?

Since Question 1 seems very difficult for me, I've been trying to find the **explicit** value of $M(a,n)$ for smaller $(a,n)$. However, even proving that $M(1,1)=1/\pi$ for $x=\pi$ was not very easy for me. So...

> **Question 2** : For what $(a,n)\not=(1,1)$ can we find the **explicit** value of $M(a,n)$?

**Edit** : I noticed that $a\ge 1\in\mathbb R$ is needed for the existence of $M(a,1)$.

Comment: The maximum occurs at $x=\pi$ whenever $a=\pi^{n-1}$. This includes the case $(a,n)=(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a analytical solution. However we can take derivative and analyse it's root. So
$$
f^\prime(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{a\cos(x)}{x^{n+1}}+\frac{a\sin(x)(n+1)}{x^{n+2}}
$$
Rearranging the terms and making $f^\prime(x)=0$ we can get the following equation
for the analysis:
$$
a\sqrt{1+\frac{(n+1)^2}{x^2}} \sin(x-\arctan(\frac{(n+1)}{x}))=x^{n-1}
$$
At least we can confirm that you are correct for the case $a=1,n=1$ because then
$$
(1+4/\pi^2)\sin(\pi-\arctan(\frac{2}{\pi})=(1+4/\pi^2)\cos(\arctan(\frac{2}{\pi}))=\frac{1+4/\pi^2}{1+4/\pi^2}=1
$$
Sorry that I cannot help you more.